# Textmate - change @TODO color inside a doc block

Tags: documentation, syntax-highlighting, textmate

I'm able to change an entire documentation block's color inside textmate by using the scope `comment.block.documentation`

However is it possible to change the color of specific words inside that docblock?

I'm refering to change the color of words or even the entire line like

```
@TODO 
@FIXME 
@CHANGED
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok... i was able to find the answer.

Bundles > Bundle Editor > Show Bundle Editor

Select the Language Javascript (note... the language has a L icon inside the Javascript item on the left list)

find for the scope named comment.block.documentation.js and modify it accordingly

```
{   name = 'comment.block.documentation.js';
        begin = '(/\*\*)\s*$';
        end = '\*/';
        beginCaptures = { 1 = { name = 'punctuation.definition.comment.js'; }; };
        endCaptures = { 0 = { name = 'punctuation.definition.comment.js'; }; };
        patterns = (
            {   name = 'meta.documentation.tag.todo.js';
                begin = '((\@)TODO)';
                end = '(?=^\s*\*?\s*@|\*/)';
            },
            {   name = 'meta.documentation.tag.fixme.js';
                begin = '((\@)FIXME)';
                end = '(?=^\s*\*?\s*@|\*/)';
            },
            {   name = 'meta.documentation.tag.changed.js';
                begin = '((\@)CHANGED)';
                end = '(?=^\s*\*?\s*@|\*/)';
            },
        );
    },
```

after you just have to change the color on the prefs window, using the declared selector!

Comment: at lack of any other answer, i'm marking this one as the best answer. Kinda lame but... i'll be watching for other answers.